How can hatred not cease by hatred? It sounds incoherent

“Hatred does not cease by hatred, but only by love; this is the eternal rule.”

This quote by the Buddha makes no sense to me. Firstly and perhaps tangentially, it speaks of an "eternal" rule, but anything related to humans and other living beings including transcendent (who are the only entities that can experience hatred - inanimate rocks can't) are not permanent according to the Buddha. But okay, leaving that aside, two questions arise:

Why is hatred something that one should strive to cease? Clearly it involves important psychological functions, and had an evolutionary benefit.

How can hatred cease by love? If I love someone from another group, and that group hates me and wants me dead including any particular person from what group, they will be stronger and more motivated to destroy me, and so there will actually be less love. Moreover, there are many cases in history where two tribes hated each other, and one exterminated the other one, and the result was no more hatred. So hatred ended up ceasing through hatred.


If someone could help me on these two points, I'd appreciate it.

The point of this amazingly lucid saying (most likely not uttered by the Buddha, because it is Dhammapada which likely predates the Buddha as is evidenced by its Jain version) is that when a certain phenomenon is going on, adding more of the same fuel will act to sustain it. For example, when a fire exists then adding firewood will help sustain it. Similarly, if a conflict exists, certain actions, such as harsh statements, and especially violence, will act as fuel, provoking further conflict.
While removing the fuel or using the opposite of the fuel will act to extinguish the phenomenon. For example, water is used to extinguish regular fire by lowering the temperature and blocking the oxygen. Similarly, love and peace making extinguishes conflicts by removing their emotional and intellectual fuel.
Your example of one side of the conflict killing the other only confirms the rule. The phenomenon stops when one of its necessary conditions is no longer. This may work in an ideal environment where the two tribes had no connections with the rest of the world but in real life the embers of the conflict will remain (eg in their descendants or relatives looking for revenge) and the conflict is likely to reignite in the future.

"This may work in an ideal environment where the two tribes had no connections with the rest of the world" In some cases, this was basically true because a small and relatively isolated area was populated by a tiny number of tribes. It is/was a historical reality. G3n0c1d3 is a real phenomena historically, perhaps even more so in certain tribal environments.

It has now dawned on me that if a tribe gets away with exterminating another tribe because they hate them so much, it will only teach them that they can get their way using hate. This hate will then be taught as a positive thing, and will likely be directed against other tribes in the future, whom might be stronger and cause hatred back. So hatred doesn't necessarily cease in absolute terms in the long-run.

Yeah but also, guess what, we learn about these events and they provoke responses in us, hundreds of years later, triggering hatred in some, even today.

Fair enough I guess.

@AndriyVolkov wait..Dhammapada comes from jain suttas? Can you give sources/lijnks for this? As a great admirer of jainism, I would definitely love to read that. Thanks

Dhammapada does not "come" from Jain suttas. There are 2 or 3 versions with some differences, and many verses in common. One of these is a Jain text. This indicates the collection probably predates the Buddha.

There are no eternal beings, but there are eternal rules. Like gravity is pretty much eternal. Or like being angry is painful, and it will always be.
Hatred causes suffering in the moment. If you are angry, frustrated, irritated, etc., at that moment you are suffering.
It also produces bad results. If someone kills an entire town to get rid of hatred, it's almost sure he'll experience hell in his next life. And his current life is likely going to be full of fear, anger and pain.
The opposite of that is loving kindness. Wishing others to be well, wishing others suffer less, being happy about their success, etc.
If someone is kind, he will have a better life now. Even sleeping is easier without fear and anger. And his future lives are much more likely to be good too.
Hatred ceases by love because they are opposites states of mind. You can't wish someone to get hurt, and at the same time wish him to be happy or suffer less. If right now you wish someone to be happy, you are not experiencing hatred and its accompanying suffering.
I understand that this isn't compatible with war. Like in your example. It's very difficult to practice Buddhism in such situations.
But luckily most of us aren't going through war. Most difficult situations can be dealt using Buddhism without much problem. If you are angry at someone or someone is angry at you, often you can just stay apart for example. Or show some kindness and see if the situation improves. Even much more forceful solutions like calling the cops are mostly compatible. So it's usually not a problem for us.
But hatred is always going to result in suffering for you now, and in the future, and for the other person. So it's better to try to replace it by kindness.
I hope that helps.

this is just a silly definition game, not reality

where i live they all call each other cops, not just police, like if i say this is NJ, they will just call me a cop, so these are the new rules, and kindness just means u accept the new rules without discrimination. works good, police don't feel bad

With "wishing others well, ..." I meant the 4 Brahmaviharas. I didn't use the term, and I didn't mention equanimity, because I tried to keep it simple and easy to understand.
With "cops" I was talking casually about using force to stop situations. I wasn't discriminating them. It's just their role. In my country there are no movements in favor or against cops, it's not a thing. Metta. @blue_ego

Why is hatred something that one should strive to cease?
I think it's seen (or experienced) as painful, suffering, unpleasant -- for the person who feels hatred and for the person who is the object of the hatred.
Clearly it involves important psychological functions, and had an evolutionary benefit.
I don't think that's clear at all.
Preschoolers might cry, and hit or bite people and so on, but (in my experience) they're taught that that's unskilful behaviour (or "bad behaviour").
Moreover, there are many cases in history where two tribes hated each other, and one exterminated the other one, and the result was no more hatred.
The "explanation" for that verse is a story about people who hated in other in a previous life.

https://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=005


Once there lived a householder, whose wife was barren; later he took another wife. The feud started when the elder wife caused abortion of the other one, who eventually died in child birth. In later existences the two were reborn as a hen and a cat; a doe and a leopardess; and finally as the daughter of a nobleman in Savatthi and an ogress named Kali. The ogress (Kalayakkhini) was in hot pursuit of the lady with the baby, when the latter learned that the Buddha was nearby, giving a religious discourse at the Jetavana monastery. She fled to him and placed her son at his feet for protection. The ogress was stopped at the door by the guardian spirit of the monastery and was refused admission. She was later called in and both the lady and the ogress were reprimanded by the Buddha. The Buddha told them about their past feuds as rival wives of a common husband, as a cat and a hen, and as a doe and a leopardess. They were made to see that hatred could only cause more hatred, and that it could only cease through friendship, understanding and goodwill.

You may or may not prefer to interpret that as metaphorical.
More to the point, you may be taking the verse out of context. If you look at the previous verses, I think it's to do with whether hatred ceases in your own mind -- and continuing to hate won't do it.
Killing might not be the answer either: on a personal level there's PTSD that haunts people; on a social level you see old enmities (e.g. "anti-nazi") are deliberately perpetuated for generations.
I'm not saying it's right to love e.g. a mass-murderer either -- but the Buddha for example didn't hate a mass-murderer, and did allow him to become a monk (though only after he stopped murdering, of course) -- I think it's an axiom of preschool teachers to distinguish "bad behaviours" from "bad children", i.e. to correct (or remove the occasion for) bad behaviours, without labelling children as "bad".

Maybe "hate" is "energy" (depending on how you define the words -- e.g. I once heard in a non-Buddhist context "depression" described as "anger without enthusiasm" but maybe that was a joke). I was wondering about "self-confidence" as a virtue, given Buddhism's "no self" theorem -- maybe the Buddhist virtue is translated as "strength", or "energy" as you say, i.e. viriya. Maybe it has good and bad, skillful and less skilful forms/aims/results, like chanda too https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/thai/suwat/attitude.html

i read "Depression is the result of resistance to what is - basically suppressed anger, when the ego don’t get it want it wants"  - i can't recall the title, but it was a self-help book, so i guess it couldn't be buddhist...hehe

And as for the existence of the word "hate", I'm not sure what you were saying but children are quite literally taught to label their emotions, e.g. to say "I'm angry because ..." instead of 'lashing out' -- they're reminded to "use your words". Those who aren't good at it (e.g. with "behavioural problems") are taught in more detail how to recognize their own anger (e.g. fists clenched, ears hot, etc.). I'm not an expert (i.e. teacher) but presumably that's meant to help, anyway it implies that what we (now) know as "hate" preexisted before we knew the word!

It is actually a rather simple tautological statement, but super important nonetheless.
Let's say you are in a cold room with the remote control of the AC in your hand. You are suffering because of the coldness. What should you do? Get warmth? or pump up the AC even more?
"Coldness does not cease by [adding] colness, only by warmth. This is an eternal rule. "
or
"Debt does not cease by [borrowing] debt, only by paying/non-borrowing. This is an eternal rule."
I do not mean to mock the teaching or anything- I absolutely love it. I am just trying to illustrate that it is just basic understanding that love is polar opposite of hate, yet this escapes pretty much all of us due to delusion.

Actually the verse is hate and non hate.
Non hate includes metta, but it also includes upekkha (benevolence and equanimity.)
One who has a heart of non-hate, can not have hate. This is why non-hate extinguishes hate, it is its opposite.
A basic teaching of Buddhism is overcoming by opposite.
A true person is one who is thankful and grateful. One who has Dana (generosity), Sila (virtue ie precepts and in good action) & Bhavana (mental cultivation) or Sila (virtue), Samadhi (absorption based on right view) and Punyya (wisdom; seeing things clearly inline with Dhamma/Vinaya). One who has Hiri Ottappa (sense of shame and fear of consequences). One who has brahmavihara (divine emotions). One who is devoted to practice.
So all these things are essential in being a good person.
Brahmavihara, as mentioned, is essential to Buddhism. A Buddha always acts out of one of the four divine emotions (brahmaviharas). This explains why the Lord Buddha acts differently at different times, it depends on which one the Lord places His mind in at that time.
If one has metta .. k... m... or upekkha, hatred can not arise.
Hate is under one five hindrances which block meditation and the factors of awakening; ill will. One simile it is seen as bubbling water (like a fire under the mind stopping it from being still and calm).
Also in the other similes of the hindrances it is seen as a grave affliction/illness. To be free from hate is like that illness finally ends and one becomes well and is happy because of that.
Hate is also likened to a ball of lava that you throw at another. You burn yourself and don't know if you will hit them or not.
Also if someone make a meal and gives it to you, you don't have to accept it, so to if someone is angry you don't have to accept their anger. For example, just forgive them and see it as defilements arising, it's not our concern. They have suffering, we all have suffering until we are arahants (enlightened). Don't get caught up on others defilements, we are taught to look into our own hearts and work on ourselves, this is where the real work is.
Thus anger, in our own evolution, has nothing good, like a thorny tree we climb to get fruit, we scratch ourselves deeply and painfully on the way to get the fruits but nothing good comes out of it.
It is also probably listed in MN 8 under the Sallekha Sutta, as one of the 44 things to be contemplated to overcome on the path to enlightenment, there are things that must be overcome to realise enlightenment and this Sutta explicitly outlines them.
So Buddhism totally rejects hatred as unuseful, unwholesome, bad and evil characteristic.
Though it is not a worldly love. The simile given is like a nurse would remove a stick from a childs mouth even if they had to draw blood, so too one helps another for their true spiritual welfare. So its not the lovey dovey worldly idea but rather one that it is looking at true spiritual welfare of a being. This is why some enlighten beings are so spiritually fiery, as its a whole other level of what benevolence really means; they are thinking of beings true wellfare.
Hatred is also listed under the 10 wholesome/unwholesome qualities. I will give the positive form mentioned in the right view sutta in MN, slightly elaborated.
Door of body

Abstaining from killing
Abstaining from stealing
Abstaining sexual misconduct

Door of speech

Abstaining from lying/ false speech
Abstaining from harsh speech
Abstaining from slanderous speech/ divisive speach/ divisive gossip
Abstaining from idle talk

Door of Mind

Abstaining from thoughts of covertedness
Abstain from thoughts of Hatred
Developing Thoughts of Right views

If one was to perfect these 10 things they would realise path and fruit and become an arahant. In fact it is the first listing under right view in the right view sutta (though with more details given including the eightfold path which is essential to putting feet and motion onto the path of practice).
Hatred is one of the three unwholesome (akusala) roots, and those with this character trait are said to be the first to become enlightened when they final get down to do the work (the other character traits are greed next (to realise) and then delusion temperament realises usually last). So in this sense it is seen as a character trait that does bring some good, but we have to get to the end of the path before we can fully appreciate this!
Brahma's, higher gods are so because of Sila, Hiri Ottappa and Brahmavihara. They have developed metta or non hate as with all heavenly beings. It is apart of the fabric of their minds that has helped them be reborn in such a fortunate temporary birth.
So divine emotions are important in enlightenment and in goodness of heart and future birth for those as yet enlightened. They are default for fully enlightened beings.
Usually all the Brahmaviharas are developed by one who practices meditation until their practice deeply refines. It is good to have Noble teachers and Sangha to help one on the Path, so the basics can be established.
Metta is profound and there is a sutta that teaches us the benefits.

"He sleeps in comfort.
He awakes in comfort.
He sees no evil dreams.
He is dear to human beings.
He is dear to non-human beings.
Devas (gods) protect him.
Fire, poison, and sword cannot touch him.
His mind can concentrate quickly.
His countenance is serene.
He dies without being confused in mind.
If he fails to attain arahantship (the highest sanctity) here and now, he will be reborn in the brahma-world.


Interestingly the final moment of a being practicing for arahantship is upekkha to all saṅkhāra (A mind of equi-pose/equanimity to all phenomena in the universe of name and form, body and mind, as it was, as it will be and as it is.)
So this is why I don't think translating this as love is correct (non hate is better), as uppekha of an arrahat is the noble abiding that is closest to Nibbana and a pleasant abiding for them. Thus non hate includes metta, but it also include upekkha.
